# How to prevent event bubbling, rightnavbutton? Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

Here is my alloy code - snippet:

```
    <RightNavButton>
        <Button id="btnRight" onClick="rightButtonClicked" />
    </RightNavButton>
```

JS:

```
//edit profile button
function rightButtonClicked(e) {

    Ti.API.info("testing bubble ");

    //TODO: add functionality here
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

The event still bubbles. Normal buttons this works fine.

Thanks

Update:

```
<RightNavButton>
            <Button id="btnRight" title='Chat' onClick="rightButtonClicked" bubbleParent='false'/>
        </RightNavButton>
```

Still bubbles. i.e. if I click on that multiple times, it keeps on opening windows. Rather then wait for event to finish and then fire again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: Some additional detail/explanation would benefit this answer.

Comment: Is that IOS or android, my app is IOS based

Answer (score 0):

you should used bubbleParent property over the button, set it to false it will work. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-bubbleParent)